# I use json-server to post data with fetch the data added but the page reloaded even I use e.preventDefault, I need the page not reloaded

Tags: javascript, backend, fetch-api, form-submit, preventdefault

I use json-server to post data with fetch after I click submit button the data added but the page reloaded even I use e.preventDefault, I need the page not reloaded, I don't understand the problem

html code

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="" placeholder="first name" />
  <input type="text" name="lastName" id="" placeholder="last name" />
  <button type="submit">send user</button>
</form>
```

javascript code

```
const postForm = document.querySelector("form");

postForm.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const firstName = postForm.firstName.value;
  const lastName = postForm.lastName.value;

  await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
    }),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
});
```

I searched for hours but I can't find the solution

Comment: the code you posted will not reload the page, i.e. it will work exactly as you expect it to - check the browser console for errors, perhaps you've done something wrong in your actual code - like having the script run before the form is in the DOM - which would be indicated in the console by an error on the line `postForm.addEventListener`

Comment: you are right the code should do exactly as I want, but it's not working the page always reloads, and no error in the console, I put the script before closing the body tag, and when I use just fetch to get the data everything works well but when I user post for sending data the page reload >> 
in command "json-server --watch db.json"

Comment: @Jaromanda X
no error, the code is working but the page reloads even I use e.preventDefault

Comment: Can you try to remove async method.

Comment: @kennarddh  >> I tried but nothing worked

Comment: @kennarddh , "Jaromanda X", thank you so much for you and for trying to help me

I found the solution to the problem. It turns out that the problem was due to VS Live Server which was detecting a change in the folder and hot-loading the app. The change was due to the backend, in the same folder,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kennarddh , @Jaromanda X, thank you so much for you and for trying to help me I found the solution to the problem. It turns out that the problem was due to VS Live Server which was detecting a change in the folder and hot-loading the app. The change was due to the backend, in the same folder,